# Did Evelyn Waugh see himself as a conservative author, and/or did others categorize him as such?

Tags: evelyn-waugh

**Directly**

Did he openly and directly declare himself belonging to the conservative tradition?

**Indirectly**

or did he do it indirectly through his view of human nature and his choice of themes in his works? For example in his works about the decline of tradition (in example Brideshead Revisited).

**Others view of him**

And did others see him as having influenced and inspired the conservative tradition?

Comment: What do you mean by conservative tradition? I can think of several meanings of that phrase.

Comment: I'm interested in hearing about all the meanings of conservatism that can be related to Evelyn Waugh, so people could just explicit state their meaning of the concept in their answer. But generally I'm thinking conservatism in the both the narrow and broad sense, so both political conservative, and conservative in more broad terms, like being defender of tradition, seeing value in preserving traditions etc.